# Having a whitespace issue with Recyclerview inside Scrolling Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-appbarlayout

Im having a white space issue in my Recyclerview inside Scrolling activity.
Please help me to resolve this problem. i have checked everything i have known such as no margins,paddings,tried by removing the FAB. but still the problem exists.

[image: Having whitespace between Appbar and recyclerview]

*My XML code:*

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/id_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: post your complete xml code, I can see some parts missing

Comment: For me it looks like your height from AppBarLayout is bigger than the content and white space appears. Replace it with wrap content

Comment: @VivekMishra : added full XML code in question .

Comment: @mhenryk: when i use wrap_content as layout height , the whole appbar disappears.

Comment: Right, make sure your layout has the proper height. To me it looks like it misses a statusbar size. Check what happens if you remove "fitsSystemWindows" from CoordinatorLayout. Keep it in AppBar though.

Comment: The code you have mentioned seems alright. Need to check the RecyclerView's list item layout.

Comment: @ChintanSoni: if item layout had any problems, i guess the whitespace should come between every Recycler view item. So its not the problem of item Layout

Comment: This problem is happening between the appbar and the recycler, doesnt seem to have anything to do with the wxh of them

Comment: Last thing to check is the theme you're using and support library version. Please check and revert back with comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlast i figured it now, 
First of all,Thanks to **[TWL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6668797/twl)** for giving me an idea by a same issue of his [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781169/android-fitssystemwindows-and-newline-interfering-with-bottomsheets) .

I removed the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Now, your notification bar's color is probably change to Transparent and looks horrible. So, i have added `<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorPrimary</item>` in styles.

Now everything is Okay.

Comment: thank you, but if you notice now, your notification bar's color is probably not part of your app's theme color because it's no longer 'under', but 'below' it now.

Comment: @TWL : yes, i changed that too by adding `<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorPrimary</item>` in styles

Answer (score 2):

Try this by removing  `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

Comment: if i put `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` the appbar will disappear.

Comment: have you try by removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` and then put `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```